# BitBucket Commit Status with meta data

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am trying to set additional meta data as seen under Builds section.

I found [this API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits/) which is used to set statuses for builds against a commit hash.

```
{
    "state": "<INPROGRESS|SUCCESSFUL|FAILED>",
    "key": "<build-key>",
    "name": "<build-name>",
    "url": "<build-url>",
    "description": "<build-description>"
}
```

But this documentation does not include information around other sections found under Builds. Say if I wanted to includes logs or artifacts how would I do that ?[image]